# How do I sum matching elements in a list of zoo objects?

Tags: r, aggregate, zoo

Suppose I have the following list of zoo objects:

```
l <- list(A1=
read.zoo(data.frame(dt=c(as.Date('2010-01-02')+0:4), val1 = 1:5)),
B2=
read.zoo(data.frame(dt=c(as.Date('2010-01-03')+0:4), val1 = 11:15)),
C2=
read.zoo(data.frame(dt=c(as.Date('2010-01-05')+0:4), val1 = 21:25)))
```

I would like to sum up corresponding elements (elements that have matching indexes). I have tried:

```
l.sum <- Reduce('+', l)
```

but the problem with this way is that it only sums the matching elements and throws any elements that aren't matching. I need to keep the sum of the elements that didn't match in all zoo objects. So given the following zoo objects in the example:

```
$A1
2010-01-02 2010-01-03 2010-01-04 2010-01-05 2010-01-06 
         1          2          3          4          5
$B2
2010-01-03 2010-01-04 2010-01-05 2010-01-06 2010-01-07 
        11         12         13         14         15 
$C2
2010-01-05 2010-01-06 2010-01-07 2010-01-08 2010-01-09 
        21         22         23         24         25
```

I expect to get the following (ignore the wrapping - it would just be 1 zoo object that looks like the following):

```
2010-01-02 2010-01-03 2010-01-04 2010-01-05 2010-01-06 
         1         13         15         38         41

2010-01-07 2010-01-08 2010-01-09 
        23         24         25
```

> NOTE: I would prefer a base R/zoo implementation. It would be
>   interesting to see other libraries solve this also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

merge the elements of the list using fill = 0, convert that back to a list and then use Reduce.

```
Reduce("+", as.list(do.call("merge", c(l, fill = 0))))
```

giving:

```
2010-01-02 2010-01-03 2010-01-04 2010-01-05 2010-01-06 2010-01-07 2010-01-08 
         1         13         15         38         41         38         24 
2010-01-09 
        25
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `zoo::merge` to combine the objects, and then `rowSums` to add them. You can drop all the but the last column if you want.

```
r = Reduce(merge, l)
r$result = rowSums(r, na.rm = TRUE)
#            init x[[i]].object x[[i]].object result
# 2010-01-02    1            NA            NA      1
# 2010-01-03    2            11            NA     13
# 2010-01-04    3            12            NA     15
# 2010-01-05    4            13            21     38
# 2010-01-06    5            14            22     41
# 2010-01-07   NA            15            23     38
# 2010-01-08   NA            NA            24     24
# 2010-01-09   NA            NA            25     25
```